# DevExpress GridView Row or Cell Selected

Tags: select, gridview, devexpress, row

How can I differ if a single cell or the entire row is selected in GridView?

I can use GridView.RowCellClick to get when any cell is selected, but inside this event, how can I know if is just a single cell that is selected or the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

My boss helped me with the solutions (thanks boss):

```
private void gridView_RowCellClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs e)
        {
            gridView.OptionsBehavior.CopyToClipboardWithColumnHeaders = gridView.GetSelectedCells().Count() > 1;
        }
```